# How can I get the name of a HttpResponseHeader?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I am able to loop through a response.Headers collection and display the value for each header like this.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postDest);
//Set up the request with needed properties etc.
HttpWebResponse response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;    
for(int i= 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++)
{
      MessageBox.Show(response.Headers[i].ToString());
}
```

But how can I get the name Field-Name for each ResponseHeader?

**Update:**

If I do this I am able to get the Field-Name and the Value.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Field-Name is: " + response.Headers.GetKey(i).ToString() + " Value is: " + response.Headers[i].ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `response.Headers.GetValues(response.Headers.GetKey(i))`

Comment: Thanks krakover. You got me headed in the right direction if you want to update your answer to jive with my update I will select it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, I should point out that you can just call `.ToString()` on the `WebHeaderCollection` object itself. (`Response.Headers.ToString()`). Now I don't really recommend this, since the official [MSDN comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection.tostring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the method says:

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not
>   intended to be used directly from your code.

However, looking at the code through ILSpy, it's not doing anything wild, just building up a list of name/value lines in a StringBuilder based on the headers. It does exclude any unnamed headers, but I think those are quite rare. And it's interesting that they didn't go to the trouble of slapping an Obsolete compiler attribute on it (maybe to pass their unit tests?)) So it's probably safe to use. But if you are worried about this, I would recommend the solution posted in the question, which uses direct indexing. Note that direct indexing is faster than the method in the accepted answer, since it doesn't rely on a String key or internal Hashtable (not that performance is likely to be a major concern in this area.)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (HttpWebResponse v in response.Headers)
{
   v.Headers.Keys.ToString();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
foreach (var key in response.Headers.AllKeys)
{
  Console.WriteLine(response.Headers[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = response.Headers.GetValues("Key")
```

or

```
 var values = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
 if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("Key", out values))
 {
     // check values
 }
```